# PuTTY Connection Manager download?

Tags: ssh, putty

Where can I still download PuTTY Connection Manager?

I am a [PuTTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) user and finally decided I need to upgrade to a tabbed [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) environment. I found a lot of threads/sites talking about PuTTY Connection Manager, but all of them pointed to missing pages/files.

Comment: 0.7.1.136 https://web.archive.org/web/20110430132113/http://puttycm.free.fr/download/puttycm.exe SHA-256: E83E1784E7F5A0D126142F312863206463C2A4F65E7A1DB6E19E55D51D4F67C0

Answer (score 24):

Try [SuperPuTTY](https://github.com/jimradford/superputty). It is similar to puttycm.

You can also try [mobaxterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) or [mremoteng](http://www.mremoteng.org/download)

Comment: I have updated the link @Mir-Ismaili

Comment: The free version of MobaXterm is limited to six PuTTY configurations.

Answer (score 15):

You can get it at *[PuTTY: Extreme Makeover Using PuTTY Connection Manager](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/03/putty-extreme-makeover-using-putty-connection-manager/)*.

Answer (score 8):

You can download it from *[Putty Connection Manager (tabbed putty): How to configure](http://www.technlg.net/windows/configure-putty-connection-manager/)*.

Answer (score 1):

I've found version 0.7.1 Alpha of PuTTY Connection Manager to be the most stable (it was previously hidden on the forums). It's available from *[PuTTY Connection Manager – Website Down](http://www.binarysludge.com/2011/11/30/putty-connection-manager-website-down/)*.

Answer (score 0):

PuTTY Session Manager is a tool that allows system administrators to organise their PuTTY sessions into folders and assign hotkeys to favourite sessions. Multiple sessions can be launched with one click. Requires MS Windows and the .NET 2.0 Runtime.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/puttysm/

Comment: This client does not support tabs

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Jocelyn : edited my answer, thanks for undoing your downvote.

Answer (score -5):

download putty connection manager from here http://www.thegeekstuff.com/scripts/puttycm.zip

Thanks

Comment: This is the putty client, not the connection manager wrapper for putty.

Comment: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/scripts/puttycm.zip

Comment: Link is work now. Content is OK. Thanks.